# Should we be reusing JPA entities

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jpa

Currently I am working for a company that has 6-7 Java EE projects. They are multi module maven projects that are all fairly large and serve different purposes. As such, their models are very different but for the most part the data is stored in the same database.

The problem, to me, is that since there are a few areas of overlap, they simply inject the existing DAOs all the way up the depedency chain. So I have

```
A-parent
 -A-JPA
 -A-DAO

B-Parent
 -B-JPA
 -B-DAO
 -A-JPA
 -B-DAO
```

etc, etc. They are really only using 2 percent of the other projects model and respective DAO.

I am trying to attempt to decouple these dependencies by simply duplicating the entities needed (and only including fields/mappings for the things that are really needed) so that the same EJB isn't deployed 7 times (or more when clustered), but apparently I'm not making a convincing argument. Can anyone help point me to an article with best practices for this situation or help bring up points to explain to him.

TLDR: I want each project to have its own set of entities even if there is a very small bit of overlap to reduce dependencies between projects as well as make it so we aren't deploying the same EJB's 7 times. My boss thinks there is nothing wrong with these being unnecessarily coupled. Am I making a big deal about this for nothing? Thanks!

Comment: This is a bit subjective and depends on a lot of factors about your specific domain.  Generally if I have 1 database being shared I would want one maven project with the dao/jpa and just have anything that needs database access include that dependency.  Separation of concerns and all.  But again, this isn't the best answer for people that arn't familiar with your project to answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a single data model that is being maintained for various applications to use, the persistence entities (and even their DAOs) may be seen as the Java API to that database, and I'd put it in a central component. Some organizations may even drive the design from the database upwards, and reverse engineer the persistence entities, in which case they'll be same or similar for different users.

Whether such central component is a library (reused by other components) or an EJB of its own (that's being called by other components) I would let depend on the desired transactional and caching behavior of the application, and how you see responsibilities being organized. On one project we strongly upheld the rule that each piece of data could only be maintained by a single component (a service or an EJB) and others would have to go through that single component.

If it is a common domain model, but every EJB implement its own data storage for that, then the domain model may be shared, and I would not share the persistence entities. Then you get into the discussion of sharing the domain model among different components. The world may be viewed in slightly different ways from within different sub-domains and I feel that you end up designing your domains slightly different across different sub-systems, hence there I would possibly vote against reuse.

Everyone's mileage may vary, and I may see things differently given the actual circumstances of a particular project.

Comment: Hrmm. I knew this was highly subjective. Basically the "overlap" from each model is a very small part. 3-5 percent is overlap?

Comment: IF we make it a singular EJB, since the 6-7 apps are being deployed in different ears, we can't use a Local EJB to share and apparently remote EJB's don't work like I think they do?